# Find biggest number in each row from a text file in java

Tags: java, file

I have to find the biggest number in each row in text file but for some reason my code only finds the biggest number in the first row.

```
File file = new File("input.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
int highScore = sc.nextInt();

while(sc.hasNextInt()){
   int grade = sc.nextInt();
   if(grade > highScore){
      highScore = grade;
   }
}
System.out.println(highScore);
sc.close();
```

I've tried many things but it only finds the biggest number in the first row. The numbers in the text file are in a 4x4 style so, first row: 4 10 2, second row: 11 5 20 and third row: 6 3 5

Comment: You need to know when a new line starts. You can read the entire line into a string, parse the integers from that, then find and print the max. Repeat for other lines.

Comment: Which part of your code is responsible for keeping track of which line each number came from?

Comment: Yes, if "row" is the same as a line of text, `nextInt()` will blow right past any next line characters.  Consider something like `readLine()` then use `string.split()` followed by `string.intValue()` to parse the lines.  (I'm trying to think of a more automatic way to do this but I can't come up with anything.)

Comment: Can you post how does your file exacly looks like?

Answer (score 2):

Given the following lines of text.

```
String text = """
      1  2 3 4 5 6
      30 20 1 30 40
      9 100, 4, 5 12 1
    """;
```

- Use `Pattern.splitAsStream(String)` to stream only the numeric values. The regex `\\D+` will split on any grouping of non digits. (Thanks to [Alexander Ivanchenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17949945/alexander-ivanchenko) for this alternative to `Arrays.stream(String.split,regex)`
- filter out any empty strings and convert to an int.
- then return the maximum.  Note:  Since `max` returns an `OptionalInt` you need to use `getAsInt()` to get the value.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(text);

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    int highScore = Pattern.compile("\\D+")
            .splitAsStream(sc.nextLine())
            .filter(s->!s.isBlank())
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
            .max().getAsInt();
    
    System.out.println(highScore);
}
```

Prints

```
6
40
100
```

For demo purposes, a text string is used.  The while loop should also work when you open a file and read with the scanner.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Good idea.  That's not the first time I have forgotten that method exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hasNextLine()` to know when a new line is being read to reset the highest score.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ScanLine {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File file = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = sc.nextLine();
      String[] nums = line.split(" ");
      
      int highScore = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i) {
        int grade = Integer.parseInt(nums[i]);
         if(grade > highScore){
            highScore = grade;
         }
      }
      System.out.println(highScore);
    }
    sc.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()), method `hasNextInt()` returns true if the next token in this scanner's input can be interpreted as an int value.

If you have input like this:

```
4 10 2,
11 5 20
6 3 5
```

Token  **2,** cant be interpreted as int value, and for this token method `hasNextInt()` will return `false`, and you will exist while loop.
Until that moment, the biggest number you will find is the number 10 and that is what you see printed on the console

Answer (score 0):

```
File aaa = new File("input.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(aaa);
int highScore = sc.nextInt();
int counter=1;

while(sc.hasNextInt()){
   int grade = sc.nextInt();
   if(counter%3==0){
      highScore = grade; 
   }
   if(grade > highScore){
      highScore = grade;
   }
   ++counter;
   if(counter%3==0){
       
       System.out.println("highScore= "+highScore+" in line number "+counter/3);
   }
}
sc.close();
```

Note:this code work if you have 3 values in each row and you can change it by changing this condition counter%3==0 change 3 to any number